# JavaScript - Match between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays

```
const statusesValues = ['progress', 'validate', 'blocked']
```

and

```
const statuses = [{status: 'progress' , id: 1}, {status: 'validate', id: 2}, {status: 'blocked', id: 3}, {status: 'no_validate', id: 4}]
```

I would like to get an array of id matches between the elements of the first array and the status properties of the second array.

In this example: `[1, 2, 3]`

What is the most elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Array#prototype#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#prototype#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const statusesValues = ['progress', 'validate', 'blocked']
const statuses = [{
  status: 'progress',
  id: 1
}, {
  status: 'validate',
  id: 2
}, {
  status: 'blocked',
  id: 3
}, {
  status: 'no_validate',
  id: 4
}]


const res = statuses
  .filter(x => statusesValues.includes(x.status.toLowerCase()))
  .map(x => x.id);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get all `id`.

```js
const
    statusesValues = ['progress', 'validate', 'blocked'],
    statuses = [{ status: 'progress', id: 1 }, { status: 'validate', id: 2 }, { status: 'blocked', id: 3 }, { status: 'no_validate', id: 4 }],
    ids = statusesValues.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        new Map(statuses.map(({ status, id }) => [status, id]))
    );

console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
const matches = statuses
            .filter(status => statusesValues.indexOf(status.status) > -1)
            .map(status => status.id);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your statuses and Id are unique :

```
const statusesId = statusesValues.map(x => statuses.find(y => y.status === x).id)
```